# Is it possible to use the `substr` package to extract the name of a command, then call that command?

Tags: strings, csname

Is it possible to use the `substr` package to extract the name of a command, then invoke that command?
For example:

```
\newcommand{\abc}{yay}

\csname \BeforeSubString{|}{abc|def}\endcsname
```

What I want to see:

```
yay
```

What I see:

```
Missing \endcsname inserted. [\csname \BeforeSubString{|}{abc|def}]
Extra \endcsname. [...ame \BeforeSubString{|}{abc|def}\endcsname]
```

Comment: `\BeforeSubString` is not expandable, so it won't work there. Do you need to use `\BeforeSubString` or some other command/package will do?

Comment: it can be any command that achieves that goal. any package is fine.

Comment: what does expandable/not expandable mean?

Comment: TeX works by expanding macros (for example, expanding `\abc` to `yay`), but some operations are not expandable, which means that they need to be processed in a deeper level by TeX. See the second part of [this answer](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/497369/134574) for a brief description of that. If you want to read more, then see [this thread](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/35039/134574) too.

Comment: hmm, so is it safe to say that string parsing is beyond the scope of latex? sorry I am new and don't know anything :)

Comment: I wouldn't say that. There are many packages for string manipulation, and they do their job very well. The problem is that `\csname`...`\endcsname` _requires_ that everything inside it be expandable. And while it is possible to make many useful macros expandable (for example, `expl3` contains an expandable floating point unit!), the code is usually much more complex than an unexpandable code. For an example of this extra complication, compare the code in [this question](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/492443/134574) with the same code in my answer to see the difference in the amount of code.

Comment: hmm these examples are way beyond my latex knowledge. i guess i am just trying to figure out if what I want to do is possible or not. and if so, how would I do it?

Comment: As I said, it is possible to make a lot of interesting things expandably. It's just a tad more complicated. I'm writing something for you.

Comment: What would be a use case? It's quite possible that a different solution can be devised.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Here's an expandable version of `\BeforeSubString` which I (with all my creativity) called `\ExpBeforeSubString`:

```latex
\documentclass{article}

\makeatletter
\def\ExpBeforeSubString#1#2{%
  \expandafter\befsub@detoki\expandafter{\detokenize{#2}}{#1}}
\def\befsub@detoki#1#2{%
  \expandafter\befsub@detokii\expandafter{\detokenize{#2}}{#1}}
\def\befsub@detokii#1#2{%
  \rn@ifsinglechar{#1}%
    {\befsub@loop{}{#1}#2\q@rec@tail\q@rec@stop}%
    {\errmessage{`#1' should be a single, non-empty token.}}}
\def\q@rec@tail{\q@rec@tail}
\def\befsub@loop#1#2#3{%
  \befsub@iftail{#3}%
    {\befsub@return{#1}}%
    {%
      \befsub@match{#2}{#3}%
        {\befsub@return{#1}}%
        {\befsub@loop{#1#3}{#2}}%
    }%
}
\def\befsub@match#1#2{%
  \if#1#2%
    \expandafter\@firstoftwo
  \else
    \expandafter\@secondoftwo
  \fi}
\def\befsub@return#1#2\q@rec@stop{#1}
\def\befsub@iftail#1{%
  \ifx\q@rec@tail#1%
    \expandafter\@firstoftwo
  \else
    \expandafter\@secondoftwo
  \fi}
\edef\rn@catofamp{\the\catcode`\&}
\catcode`\&=11
\long\def\rn@gobble#1&{%
  \romannumeral-`0\rn@@gobble#1\rn@qrtail &}
\long\def\rn@@gobble#1#2&{%
  \ifx\rn@qrtail#1%
    \expandafter\rn@@gobble@end
  \else
    \expandafter\rn@de@tail
  \fi#2}
\def\rn@@gobble@end{ }
\long\def\rn@de@tail#1\rn@qrtail{ #1}
\long\def\rn@ifsinglechar#1{%
  \rn@ifempty{#1}%
    {\@secondoftwo}%
    {%
      \if\relax\expandafter\rn@gobble\detokenize{#1}&\relax
        \expandafter\@firstoftwo
      \else
        \expandafter\@secondoftwo
      \fi
    }%
}
\catcode`\&=\rn@catofamp
\long\def\rn@ifempty#1{%
  \if\relax\detokenize{#1}\relax
    \expandafter\@firstoftwo
  \else
    \expandafter\@secondoftwo
  \fi
}
\makeatother

\begin{document}

\newcommand{\abc}{yay}
\csname \ExpBeforeSubString{|}{abc|def}\endcsname

\end{document}
```

Now using

```latex
\newcommand{\abc}{yay}
\csname \ExpBeforeSubString{|}{abc|def}\endcsname
```

yields `yay`. Yay!

Compare the length of code with the original (non expandable) version:

```latex
\makeatletter
\newcommand*\BeforeSubString[2]{%
  \su@ExpandTwoArgs{#1}{#2}\su@BeforeSubString
}
\newcommand*\su@BeforeSubString[2]{%
  \def\su@rest##1#1##2\@nil{##1}%
  \IfSubStringInString{#1}{#2}{\su@rest#2\@nil}{#2}%
}
\newcommand\su@ExpandTwoArgs[3]{%
  \protected@edef\su@SubString{#1}%
  \protected@edef\su@String{#2}%
  \expandafter\expandafter\expandafter#3%
  \expandafter\expandafter\expandafter{%
    \expandafter\su@SubString\expandafter
  }\expandafter{\su@String}%
}
\newcommand*\IfSubStringInString[2]{%
  \su@ExpandTwoArgs{#1}{#2}\su@IfSubStringInString
}
\newcommand*\su@IfSubStringInString[2]{%
  \def\su@compare##1#1##2\@nil{%
    \def\su@param{##2}%
    \ifx\su@param\@empty
      \expandafter\@secondoftwo
    \else
      \expandafter\@firstoftwo
    \fi
  }%
  \su@compare#2\@nnil#1\@nil
}
\makeatother
```

Or a version with `xstring` which allows you to store the match in a temporary macro:

```latex
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{xstring}

\begin{document}

\newcommand{\abc}{yay}
\StrBefore{abc|def}{|}[\tempmacro]
\csname\tempmacro\endcsname

\end{document}
```

Comment: omg thank you so much!! I thought I was just asking a simple question, i guess latex is much less powerful than I expected!

Comment: sorry i am not allowed to vote up but if i could i would

Comment: @14jbella It's not _that_ complicated, compared to other pieces of code out there. The first code has a bunch of security features to guarantee it will not explode, plus the extra complication for expandable code. You are facing this extra complication because you need/want expandability here, but you can always use the `xstring` version, which just requires an additional step. And I disagree, TeX can be quite powerful! Of course there are some things it simply can't do, but all languages have their limitations. (cont'd)

Comment: @14jbella If you want to give a try at programming in LaTeX, I suggest you take a look at [`expl3`](http://linorg.usp.br/CTAN/macros/latex/contrib/l3kernel/interface3.pdf). It's an attempt at providing a consistent programming API for LaTeX, which allows you do write some complicated code with relatively less effort. As I said, TeX can be quite powerful, you just have to get used to its oddities. Once you do, it's a quite fun procrastination tool :-) (P.S.: Don't worry about votes. However, you can mark the question as “solved” by clicking the check mark below it, if you want to.)

Comment: The are three things a man must do before his life is done; write two lines in expl3 and make the buggers run.  (Stolen from The Devil's DP Dictionary, more or less).