# Can I make a macro behave like \numexpr?

Tags: macros, luatex, tex-core, directlua

For example I define `\fpeval` in Plain LuaTeX:

```
\begingroup
\catcode`\%=12
\directlua{
   function math.round_int ( x )
     return x>=0 and math.floor(x+0.5) or math.ceil(x-0.5)
   end
   function math.round ( x , n )
     return math.round_int ( x*10^n ) / 10^n 
   end
   function gobblezero(x)
     local y = math.round ( x , 8 )
     if y == math.floor(y) then
       return string.format ( "%.0f", y )
     else
       return math.round(y, 7)
     end
   end}
\endgroup

\def\fpeval#1{\directlua{tex.print(gobblezero(#1))}}

\directlua{%
    p = 68
    P = 80}

You have \fpeval{p} of \fpeval{P} points, this makes $\fpeval{p * 100/P}\,\%$.

\bye
```

But I would like to have a macro called `\fpexpr` that behaves like `\numexpr`, so that I can write:

```
You have \fpexpr p of \fpexpr P points, this makes $\fpexpr p * 100/P \,\%$.
```

In the first case `\fpexpr` should take only `p` as the argument because `of` has never been defined to be a number or a function like `\directlua{of = ...}`. The second and the third case are similar as `points` and `\,` are undefined in the Lua interpreter.

So `\fpexpr` should add everything to the lua code until something would be added that would cause an error.

Is this possible?

Comment: You would have to define rules for what delimits a valid argument.

Comment: @DavidCarlisle I mean parsing an arbitrary Lua expression up to the first non-legal token as in the third case. ;)

Comment: to do this in full generality would require full lua interpreter and multiple back tracing eg after  `\fpeval 3+ zzz` you would presumably need to consume the + then see zzz and back up and just take a 3.

Comment: Trying to make a defined macro act like `\numexpr` is very hard.  See Phelype's answer at https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/492443/understanding-implicit-delimiters-terminators

Comment: I can't see any way this is remotely feasible in luatex.

Comment: you could add the tokens one by one and catch errors but how can you tell when to stop `\fpexpr p` error-free, `fpexpr p *` error  `\fpexpr p * 100` error-free `\fpexpr p * 100 /` error, `\fpexpr p * 100/P` error-free, `\fpexpr p * 100/P \,` how do you know to stop here?

Comment: @DavidCarlisle I have been thinking about this for some hours - without success.

Comment: @WeißerKater I have a plan.... might post an answer in a bit

Comment: You would "just" need to write a parser+interpreter for Lua expressions in Lua. :-)

Comment: Here comes the "purely academic" view, which is of no use at all: Implementing in terms of macros and `\directlua` a "mechanism" that in all aspects behaves like `\numexpr`  will be difficult, to say the least: Behaving like `\numexpr` implies that evaluability depends on the same conditions as the evaluability of `\numexpr`. For example, `\numexpr` is not expandable, but can be evaluated by prepending `\the` (or `\number`) or when assigning values to count registers or TeX integer parameters and the like. :-)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

[image]

This is far from complete but it does some cases.

It is very chatty on the terminal:

```
token is p
variable found 68 p
token is of
stop at of collected: 68
2: eval result is 68 x
token is P
variable found 80 P
token is points,
stop at points, collected: 80
2: eval result is 80 x
token is p
variable found 68 p
token is *
token is 100
token is /
token is P
variable found 80 P
token is ?
1: eval result is 85.0
```

code is

```
\begingroup
\catcode`\%=12
\directlua{
   function math.round_int ( x )
     return x>=0 and math.floor(x+0.5) or math.ceil(x-0.5)
   end
   function math.round ( x , n )
     return math.round_int ( x*10^n ) / 10^n 
   end
   function gobblezero(x)
     local y = math.round ( x , 8 )
     if y == math.floor(y) then
       return string.format ( "%.0f", y )
     else
       return math.round(y, 7)
     end
   end}
\endgroup

\def\fpeval#1{\directlua{tex.print(gobblezero(#1))}}

{\catcode`\%=12
\xdef\pc{%}
}

\directlua{
function zz (s)
local t = token.scan_string()
print ('token is ' .. (t or '?'))
if (t == nil) then
local f = loadstring('r= ' .. s)
f()
print('1: eval result is ' .. (r or '?'))
tex.print(r)
else
% t is local variable or operator or number (inexact pattern)
if (_G[t] \string~= nil) then
% recurse with value
print ('variable found ' .. _G[t] .. ' ' .. t)
 zz(s .. _G[t])
else if(string.find(t,'^[+-/*().]?\pc d*$')) then
% recurse
 zz(s .. t)
else
% evaluate string so far and retrun result and the rejected token
print('stop at ' .. t ..  ' collected: ' .. s)
local f = loadstring('r= ' .. s)
f()
print('2: eval result is ' .. (r or '?') .. ' x')
tex.print(r .. ' ' .. t )
end
end
end
end
}

\def\fpzz{\directlua{zz('')}}

\directlua{%
    p = 68
    P = 80}

You have \fpzz p of \fpzz P points, this makes $\fpzz p * 100 / P \,\%$.

\bye
```

Comment: Thank you for the answer. Now I think how to avoid the crashes in some cases like `\fpzz 1*1`, `\fpzz math.sin(1)` and `\fpzz 1 * 1 * a ...`.

Comment: @WeißerKater yes you may notice I already cheated a bit and added space `/  P`  so the variable was a separate token not `/P`  you could add known functions as well, but really I think the answer is don't do this. It's Ok for an evening amusement but I can not see this ever being robust enough to be in a real document, and has no real advantages over using a brace group around the expression.

Comment: OK, I accept your argument ... Maybe it is my lazyness. There are so much braces, I would like to avoid some of them.

Comment: @WeißerKater avoiding braces is usually a bad idea even in tex, but in luatex you have a two language system and you are wanting to drop the marking of language boundaries so having to implement an in-language parser to detect where the lua ends which is syntacticaly exceedingy weird even if you make it work.  if you don't like braces use some other terminator `\relax` or `!` or whatever and grab the whole thing as tex-delimited argument `\def\fpxx#1\relax{\directlua{whatever(#1)}` you could even use a space as the terminator (and then just use `{..}` if you need a space mid expression

Comment: So, implementing `\numexpr` and `\dimexpr` was a bad idea? Now I see how complicated this has probably been.

Comment: @WeißerKater they are a same language system, so don't have the parse issues here, but the syntax isn't great and of course latex and expl3 syntax hides that and exposes consistent brace delimited arguments,